# Use where with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im working on a node + mongodb project. I want to filter all the active profile. Here is my code.

```
  async getAllProfiles() {
    const profiles = await Profile
      .find({ $where: () => activeProfile: true  })
      .populate('user');
    return profiles;
  }
```

This doesn't work as expected. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run $where with this. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#example

```
  async getAllProfiles() {
    const profiles = await Profile
      .find({$where:"this.activeProfile==true"})
      .populate('user');
    return profiles;
  }
```

But instead of using $where you can just run cond in find, will be more faster

```
  async getAllProfiles() {
    const profiles = await Profile
      .find({activeProfile: true})
      .populate('user');
    return profiles;
  }
```

Comment: `this` with arrow function won't work as you expect. You should use `function() {...}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getAllProfiles = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Profile.find({activeProfile:true },(profileErr,profileRes)).populate('user').exec((profileErr,profileRes)=>{
        if (profileErr) {
            console.log('profileErr: ', profileErr);
            reject({ status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            resolve({ status: 200, message: 'User Profile fetch Successfully.', data: profileRes })
        }
    });
});
}
```

It Work's Perfectly!!